# Migrations don't create new tables

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have models.py in a Django app that has a few models that I have the corresponding tables for in MySQL, and others that I do not.

How do I get Django to create the tables for the models that don't have them?

I tried `makemigrations` and `migrate`, but they were not delivered.

[image]

But then again, when running tests under vcc_merged/cards_browser `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'test_vcc.polls_choice' doesn't exist")`

What am I doing wrong?

---

I am using **Django 1.11.7**, **Python 3.6.3** on **MySQL 5.7**

---

[image: Project Directory]

apps.py for browser app:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.apps import AppConfig


class BrowserConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'browser'
```

---

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'vcc_merged',
    'vcc_merged.cards_browser',
    'browser',

    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: There seems to be some mismatch between the app label and the directory name of the app. Could you post the directory tree of your project, the lines of `INSTALLED_APPS` from `settings.py` holding your app(s) and eventually the file `apps.py`?

Comment: It says `Migrations for 'browser':`, but the missing table is `test_vcc.polls_choice`. The tables per default consist of the app label and the model class name, connected with underscore.

Comment: Added more info. @cezar could you please elaborate?

Comment: Your app is called `browser`. The table for `PollsChoice` should be called `browser_pollschoice`, unless you have messed something in the `Meta` options. Have you had any app called `test_vcc`? Have you renamed some apps?

Comment: Nope not renamed anything or changed `Meta`. test_tablename, however, is the table that Django creates when running tests in order not to mess with your actual DB. I do not have an app called test_vcc, I posted the project structure, and the app_names are default

Comment: You have to specify when the error occurs, if possible identify the code part that throws the error and add that information to the question. From the initial information you provided it was almost impossible to guess what's going on. You talk about migrations and then suddenly there is an error thrown. You didn't tell what caused the error.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I am trying to run the tests under vcc_merged/cards_browser. I think that the problem is django is confusing the two model files together. If I rename the model file under browser, the tests work fine

Answer (score 0):

Try with

> Python manage.py makemigrations

Than

> Python manage.py migrate

It will work for you.

Comment: Honestly, thanks for the answer but read fully what is in my post before you answer. I already have tried what you said.

Comment: you have tried with **manage.py makemigrations** once try with **python manage.py makemigrations**